# Tikz: Add arrow tip to path instead of replacing part of path

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I add an arrow tip to a path, a part of the path is replaced
so that the overall length stays the same:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, thick] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw[thick] (0, -0.2) -- (1, -0.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can achieve it, that the arrow tip is *added* to the path?

Comment: While your observation is correct, TikZ is really more concerned that the tip of the arrow end at the end of the path.  So, the question we might have for you is where do you want the tip of the arrow to go?

Comment: @A.Ellett I think he simply wants to "shift" it so that the "wings" are at the same height of the path end, instead of the tip.

Comment: You could use `shorten >=-Xpt` where X is the length of the tip itself

Comment: You can use arrowheads as decorations.

Comment: Do you want just the tip? Or do you want the line extended to join the tip? In the first case, the arrow tip will not join with the line; in the second, it will.